# I can't make firefox work with TOR

Tags: firefox

I want to use Firefox (50.1.0) with TOR on Windows 10, so installed TOR, but then realised Firefox was not using it.  Then I ran Blackbelt to configure Firefox for me, but the icon that put on my desktop did not activate TOR.  So I went through the manual procedure to set up Firefox (SockHost 127.0.0.1, port 9150, no proxy for 127.0.0.1.  There was no checkbox for Remote DNS) but when I run Firefox, Google claims there's unusual activity and makes me repeatedly jump through a Captcha 'not a robot' hoop.  I've obviously got something wrong and my internet requests are getting garbled, but how do I sort this out?  Right now I've set Firefox back to the default, so I can at least get to the net.

Comment: Also, Tor not TOR: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#WhyCalledTor

Comment: I do not see how this is a duplicate of the question you suggest.  I'm not using the Tor browser, I'm not getting weird messages from Google.  I don't know what using an exit to send a search query to Google means.When running Tor and Firefox in parallel, I want to find a way to make my Firefox queries go out into the world via Tor, and I can't find out how to do that.

Comment: Make up your mind. Is Google claiming there's unusual activity and making you jump through a Captcha hoop (in the original question) or are you not getting weird messages from Google (in your comment)?

Comment: From the info provided in your question, you have everything working properly. This is the expected behavior when using Google through Tor. Your requests are not garbled.

Comment: Sorry, I composed my most recent question, then spotted that I had confused things and thought I'd deleted it, but seem to have posted my incorrect text anyway.    I need to revisit this.  Sorry to waste  your time.